# Possible to prevent search engine spiders from infinitely crawling paging links on search results?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt, nofollow

Our SEO team would like to open up our main dynamic search results page to spiders and remove the 'nofollow' from the meta tags.  It is currently accessible to spiders via allowing the path in robots.txt, but with a 'nofollow' clause in the meta tag which prevents spiders from going beyond the first page.

`<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow">`

I am concerned that if we remove the 'nofollow', the impact to our search system will be catastrophic, as spiders will start crawling through all pages in the result set.  I would appreciate advice as to:

1) Is there a way to remove the 'nofollow' from the meta tag, but prevent spiders from following only certain links on the page?  I have read mixed opinions on rel="nofollow", is this a viable option?

`<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.mysite.com/paginglink" >Next Page</a>`

2) Is there a way to control the 'depth' of how far spiders will go?  It wouldn't be so bad if they hit a few pages, then stopped.

3) Our search results pages have the standard next/previous links, which would in theory cause spiders to hit pages recursively to infinity, what is the effect of this on SEO?

I understand that different spiders behave differently, but am mainly concerned with the big players, such as Google, Yahoo, MSN.

*Note* our Search results pages and paging links are not bot-friendly, in that they are not re-written and have a ?name=value query string, but from what I've seen spiders no longer just abort when they see the '?' as the results pages ARE getting indexed with decent page rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest you are looking at **nofollow** wrong.  Chances are the search spiders are already especially Google, Yahoo, and MSN searching the nofollow pages, because they still have to hit those pages to see if they have a noindex.

The real problem is **nofollow** doesn't actually mean *don't follow*, it just means *don't pass on my reputation to this link*.  So unless you are aggressively blocking bots, which it doesn't sound like you are, changing the ROBOTS meta tag and robot commands on links will not effect performance because they are already hitting your site.  To confirm this just look at your HTTP Server Log.

So my vote is that you will not see any problem with removing the robot limits.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen Google index a calendar system that had relative links on each page through the end of time (Jan 19, 2038 - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  We didn't notice the load on our servers until it exposed a bug in the source code dealing with dates in 2038.

I don't know about the other search engines, but Google offers a number of helpful tools for controlling how much the googlebot impacts your server infrastructure.  See http://www.google.com/webmasters/.

There is an option in webmaster tools to set the crawl rate for your site.

Answer (score 1):

Google bots are pretty intelligent about not traversing an entire database of dynamically-generated pages, as long as the URLs give some hint that they are dynamic (i.e. file extension of .asp or .jsp, etc. and numeric ids as query parameters).  If you use rewrite rules to make your URLs "friendly", then the bots have a harder time determining whether or not it's a static page they are reading or a dynamically generated page.  See [this Google article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html) for more information about dynamic vs. static URLs.

You may also want to consider creating a [Google Sitemap](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/06/webmaster-friendly.html) to give the bots a better idea about what pages on your site can be indexed and which cannot.